How bright is the sun now, as seen from Voyager?
To voyager, the sun is just the brightest star in the Galaxy at night. And it's always night. It's never the day any more. Voyager is in the dark now forever, cold and alone.
What magnitude star does the sun look like now?

A nitpick: in what sense "It long ago got dimmer than the moon"? Even if the intended meaning was "the sun as seen on the Voyager got dimmer than the full moon on Earth", this is not true; maximum apparent magnitude of a full moon is around -12.9, and the accepted answer states that Sun's magnitude sits at around -15.7 or -16 at Voyagers' distance. That means Sun is still around 15 times brighter.

YIkes! I read that the sun at Pluto is like moonlight, and I extrapolated. Fixed. == Increment the count of times I've been wrong online. I'm keeping count, and it's unacceptably high.

There is nothing like day or night for Voyager. The intensity of the sunlight at Voyager is decreasing very slowly without any cycles.

Already answered on Physics.SE. Also this is a popular question elsewhere on the web.

Moreover, there was an incorrect answer -- describing the sunlight as much dimmer than it is -- posted at the normally reliable Cornell Ask an Astronomer (this question seems to be absent from the current site).

The Sun is still quite bright for both the Voyagers, much brighter than Venus is from Earth. Currently it's around -15.7 for Voyager 1 and around -16 for Voyager 2.
Here are some magnitude plots from Horizons, for the current year, using a 5 day timestep.


Those plots should be smooth curves, the steps are just numerical rounding artifacts. From the Horizons docs:

9. Visual magnitude & surface brightness
Approximate airless visual magnitude
[...]
Magnitudes are, in principle, accurate to about +/- 0.1 magnitude. However, measurement and calibration issues mean values should be considered uncertain at the +/- 1.0 magnitude level. In practice, for solar phase angles > 90 deg, the error could exceed 1 magnitude. Reduced precision values are output for phase angles greater than 120 degrees, since the errors could be large and unknown.
[...]
Magnitude laws: Sun APmag= M - 5 + 5*log10(d), where M=4.83, d=distance from Sun (parsecs)

You can find my Sage/Python magnitude script here.

The inner Solar System looks quite small from Voyager's POV. So the inner planets are always within a degree or so of the Sun. Here's a plot for the current year (with a 5 day timestep) of the ecliptic longitude & latitude of the Sun, Earth, and Jupiter, as seen from Voyager 1.

The lon-lat plotting script may be found here.

Incidentally, the Sun as seen by the Voyagers is roughly as bright as the Full Earth as seen from the Moon. Here's a plot for the Apollo 11 Lunar Reflector site, with a 6 hour timestep.


I had no idea that it was still that bright! Your answers are always so over the top complete! thank you! But what do you mean by phase angle? We're talking about the sun.

@MissUnderstands Right, that phase angle stuff is irrelevant for the Sun. I included it because it's part of the explanation of possible errors in the magnitude that Horizons calculates.

Ahh, your script was for Venus! == Phase angle == All becomes clear!

@MissU The script is general. Eg, here I use it for Mars & Earth https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/53620/16685 It can also give magnitude estimates for asteroids or comets, but those estimates can have higher error, as explained in the Horizons docs. If you try to find the magnitude of a spacecraft, the script will crash & print an error message. ;)

For another comparison, the magnitude of a full moon on Earth is about -12.7; so the Sun is still brighter than that as seen from Voyager.

At Voyager 1's distance of 24 billion km (160AU), the sun appears mag-16 which is by far the brightest object in its celestial sphere.
By comparison, Venus maxes out at -4.9 when viewed from Earth.
The sun (absolute mag 4.8) is magnitude -27 from Earth. It will be 1/160^2 (2.5x10^-4) of that brightness at 160AU
Voyager1 is only 1/17,000 of the distance from Earth to Alpha Centauri. By interstellar standards, it is still in our back yard so the Sun still dominates the sky.


Voyager1 is only 1/17,000 of the distance from Earth to Alpha Centauri. == wow, thank you!


How far away will Voyager have to be before the Sun appears at the same brightness as Venus? How far away before the Sun is at the brightness of a full Moon?

@StevePemberton:  Every time the distance to a star increases by a factor of 10, the magnitude increases (i.e., the star gets dimmer) by 5 units.  Since the full Moon is about 3 magnitudes dimmer, the Voyagers will need to get about $10^{3/5} \approx 4$ times farther before the Sun dims to that level.  For Venus, 11 magnitudes dimmer, it needs to get about $10^{11/5} \approx 158$ times farther.
